# Run an access_by_lua before an if

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I'm trying to get some text from an api then proxy pass if it equals to something. After some testing, I discovered that the access_by_lua is getting executed after the if statement.

Here's my current code:

```
set $protectione 'disabled';

        access_by_lua_block {
local http = require "resty.http"
local httpc = http.new()

local res, err = httpc:request_uri("http://127.0.0.1/ddos/fw.json", { method = "GET" })
ngx.var.protectione = res.body

        }



   if ( $protectione = 'disabled' ) {

     proxy_pass http://backend;
       set $allowreq 1;

   }
```

Is there an alternative to my problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely should take a look at next [tutorial](http://openresty.org/download/agentzh-nginx-tutorials-en.html) and this [post](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

You don't get the idea of nginx request processing phases.

Nginx directives are not executed sequentaly.

`if` and `set` directives work on `rewrite` phase which is processed before `access` phase.

Comment: What alternative should I consider then ?